# How should I analyze differences between phyletic patterns?

Tags: python, boolean, bioinformatics, phylogeny

I have found `orthogroups` (by `OrthoFinder`) in full `archaeal proteoms` of genus `Halorubrum`. As a result I have a `dataframe` with number of proteins in each `orthogroup` of each organism (number of `orthogroup` in rows and species in columns) where I have changed every number that is more than 1 to 1 to make `phyletic` patterns. In the end I have this `dataframe`:

Phyletic patterns of genus Halorubrum - df 'ogroups_pattern:

[image: Phyletic patterns of genus Halorubrum - df 'ogroups_patterns']

There are

```
 thermophilic(['aethiopicum', 'coriense', 'tebenquichense', 'vacuolatum', 'lipolyticum', 'saccharovorum', 'terrestre', 'salsamenti','yunnanense', 'sodomense', 'distributum', 'aidingense', 'arcis'])
```

and `non-thermophilic` organisms. The question is: how should I analyze this data if my goal is to find differences of `thermophilic` patterns in compare to non-`thermophilic`?

I tried to calculate Jaccard index in every orthogroup

```
ogroups_patterns['J'] = ogroups_patterns_terms.sum(axis = 1, numeric_only = True) / ogroups_patterns.sum(axis = 1, numeric_only = True)
```

where ogroups_patterns_terms is a df with phyletic patterns as in the screenshot, but for thermophiles only

But I have no idea is this the correct way to calculate this index in this case. Maybe allowing zeros in the formula will be a good idea, but Im not sure how to code it.
Every little tip would be extremely helpful, really stucked at this part and have no ideas what to do and how to code it.
Bigbig thanking in advance!